# In a Flutter error log, how can I find the object named in the log?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

**Thanks for considering this issue. It's driving me crazy.**

Please read my question carefully before jumping in with an answer. It's probably not what you're anticipating.

A code example isn't needed to put the question, so I didn't include one. This is about how to plumb Flutter internals to locate an internal object.

Specifically, I want to learn how to locate a defunct render object in a running Flutter program that is referenced in the error log *by name*.

My question is not about using Positioned Widgets correctly, so responses specifically about them are probably not going to be useful; The use case just happens to be in terms of Positioned Widgets.

**The Use Case.**

I'm developing Flutter code which provides a Stack Widget that wraps many transient Positioned Widgets.

The Positioned widgets are swapped in and out of the Stack very rapidly.

Since the positioned Widgets themselves wrap other Widgets that change, I pass the hosting widget's setState() method to a builder function that returns a Positioned Widget.

When the Positioned Widget updates its internal state, the child calls the setState() that was passed in in order to notify the parent Widget that it needs to rebuild.

Almost all of the time this works great. Except when it doesn't.

Occasionally, Flutter throws an error like this:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library 
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
setState() called after dispose(): _TowerWidgetState#c7453(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

I understand *what's* going on, but I'm having trouble finding the object that is calling setState() incorrectly.

Clearly I'm detaching one of the Positioned Widgets from the render tree, which is then calling the setState() function that I originally passed to it, and producing an error message like the one shown above.

My frustration here is that I can't locate the faulty widget.

**Finally, the question:**

Given a reference to some Flutter object (In this example, *_TowerWidgetState#c7453*), how do I locate that object with the debugger, since clearly it's not in the widget tree anymore?

To help people frame answers, I'm developing the code using Android Studio.

**What have you already tried, Curt?**

I've tried all of these things without success:

- setting a breakpoint on the named code line
- Conditioning the breakpoint to hit on every exception type listed in the debug dialog

I've tried breaking on

- Dart Exceptions
- Java Exceptions
- Any Exceptions

I even set dozens of breakpoints just to log the code path in the hope of getting close to the errant code.

Flutter reports that the error was caught, names the offending object and keeps running. I'm completely frustrated trying to catch it in the act.

Any tactics to find and fix this elusive error would be appreciated.

I would be happy to provide any specifics that would help to answer the question.

Comment: As regards the actual 'bug', it turned out that ' _animationController.forward().orCancel()' was the culprit. On an Android build, the 'orCancel()' will make the framework throw an error. This doesn't happen on iOS. I just dropped the '.orCancel()'.

However, my question still stands unanswered. :)

Comment: Slightly over a year later, I can only add to this mystery that judicious addition of assert() inside the suspicious code eventually revealed where my code was holding on to a reference to a list of disposed() widgets. I never actually learned how to trace down to an instance.